# String scanners

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm tryin to ask the user to select a package by entering the letters A, B, C || a, b, c

I'm stuck, help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
public class AssignmentFive {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String A = "You chose package A";
        String B = "You chose package B";
        String C = "You chose package C";

        System.out.println ("Package A: For $9.95 per month, 10 hours of access is provided. Additional hours are $2.00 per hour.");
        System.out.println("Package B: For $13.95 per month, 20 hours of access is provided. Additional hours are $1.00 per hour");
        System.out.println("Package C: For $19.95 per month, unlimited access is provided");

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Please enter the letter of the package you want");

        Scanner value = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(value.nextLine());

        if(userinput) {
            System.out.println(B);
        }        

    }
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem:      userinput cannot be resolved to a variable  at
>   Assignments.AssignmentFive.main(AssignmentFive.java:24)

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what is wrong, you have never created variable `userInput`

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String A = "You chose package A";
        String B = "You chose package B";
        String C = "You chose package C";

        System.out.println ("Package A: For $9.95 per month, 10 hours of access is provided. Additional hours are $2.00 per hour.");
        System.out.println("Package B: For $13.95 per month, 20 hours of access is provided. Additional hours are $1.00 per hour");
        System.out.println("Package C: For $19.95 per month, unlimited access is provided");

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Please enter the letter of the package you want");

        Scanner value = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userinput = value.nextLine().toUpperCase();

        if((userinput.equals("A")))
            System.out.println(A);
        else if ((userinput.equals("B")))
            System.out.println(B);
        else if ((userinput.equals("C")))
            System.out.println(C);
        }
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer WHY their code doesn't work. An explanation of your code might help them learn.

Comment: @Pamplemousse9 Noted. Thanks


@ mathias-payne So the reason you got this error is because you have used a variable which the complier didn't recognise.

Common reasons for this error are : 
1) In your case the variable is not declared 
2) Or the variable is not within the scope of the method
3) in case of class, incorrectly importing of the class 
4) or imported class doesn't exists

Hope this help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your `userInput` variable as the exception says. This particular exception is compile time exception and you need to resolve it before running the program.

Also you need to modify your `if` condition as it depends how you define userInput variable. Currently it is excepting as boolean variable. If you define userInput as string then you have to user `equals` method to verify the user input.